# Why does not rectangle make a perfect match when called Create in manim

Tags: manim

When I run this code

```py
from manim import *


class App(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        rectangle = Rectangle()
        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(rectangle))
```

it draws a thin rectangle first, then the borders get thick. I wanted to remove that second part of the animation, and decided to play `Create` instead of `DrawBorderThenFill`.

But when I do that, here's how my rectangle looks like

[image]

as you can see, the upper right corner doesn't match. Why is that so, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Using manim community v0.18.0 I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, testing both Create and DrawBorderThenFill. How did you create the image? Maybe the animation was not completely ready because I see no self.wait() in your code.

Comment: You are correct, it was because of the missing wait method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulating my comment as an answer.
Adding

```py
self.wait()
```

at the end of the script should solve the issue.